# macvim insert cursor disappears

Tags: cursor, macvim

MY macvim was working fine, but I just opened it and the insert mode cursor disappears, it also hides anything under it, so it's really hard to read anything or find whre the cursor is.
I just removec macvim and reinstalled https://github.com/alexlovelltroy/macvim/downloads but still have the same problem.
I've seen people have problem with normal cursor but not the insert mode.
any ideas?

Comment: It is likely this has more to do with your settings than the version of MacVim (e.g. ~/.vimrc, ~/.gvimrc, or ~/.vim/**). You might try temporarily renaming these files to see if settings are the problem.

Comment: Specifically you might want to look for a `guicursor` setting somewhere.